# Deleting the document according to the condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Assume I have db as;

```
{
  id: 1,
  address: 
    [
      {type: "home" , street: ""},  
      {type: "work" , street: ""},
      {type: "school" , street: ""}
    ]
}
```

I want to delete some `address` objects according to their type.

For example to delete `type: "school"` with `id : 1` I wrote a query as;

```
db.collection.update({ "id" : 1}, {$pull : {"address" : {"type" : "school"}}}
```

By this way I can delete each object of the `address` field.

But what I wonder is; Is it possible to delete the document when query deletes the last object of the `address`.

Let me clarify by an example;

collection has;

```
{
  id: 1,
  address: 
    [
      {type: "school" , street: ""}
    ]
}
```

query is;

```
db.collection.update({ "id" : 1}, {$pull : {"address" : {"type" : "school"}}}
```

the result of the query, document becomes;

```
{
  id: 1,
  address: 
    [

    ]
}
```

What I want is delete the `document` with `id:1` and get nothing as a result of the query.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Would `$unset` the fields which have `$size = 0` work for you?

Comment: It says "The $unset operator deletes a particular field." in mongodb document https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/ . Is it possible to delete the document with $unset?

Comment: After this query, I execute `db.component.deleteMany({address: {$size: 0}})` and it deletes documents which don't include `adress` objects.  
Is it the best way to do it?